# Access to path denied and some other errors when using Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

- Script runs perfectly from the Powershell terminal
- Problem only occurs when run using Task Scheduler
- I don't have Admin privileges and am running this using `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
- Possibly my admin has locked my access to C:\, but creating folders and accessing that is OK

Here is the error output:

```
out-file : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\1' is denied.
At C:\scripts\xxx.ps1:7 char:4
 + if($day>1){$offset= -2}
 +  
 + CategoryInfo: OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Fileopenfailure,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

If the full code is needed I can remove the auth portions and put it up.

Comment: `if($day>1)` - that's not the PowerShell greater than operator, that's file redirection. You want `-gt`. *Script runs perfectly from the Powershell Terminal* - presumably not; you've just never noticed that it writes a file called `1` and doesn't test the day number.

Comment: oh my good lord so that was it. thank you so much - it works now!